# nginx + gunicorn on EC2 - 502 (No such file)

Tags: nginx, gunicorn, nginx-config

I have a setup on Amazon EC2 consisting of nginx + gunicorn + flask.
I almost followed exactly the same to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1D4mn_rO2cM&ab_channel=CodeWithMuh). The video is based on this [medium](https://codewithmuh.medium.com/host-django-application-using-gunicorn-nginx-in-production-on-aws-ubuntu-server-4b1551e13c66)

##### Problem

When I try to POST http://[publicIPv4]:80/diagnosis, it only returns 502 Error.

[nginx error log]

```
2023/11/29 16:50:22 [crit] 14636#14636: *1 connect() to unix:/run/myproject.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: , server: localhost,  request: "POST /diagnosis HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/myproject.sock:/diagnosis", host:
```

##### Flask

home/ubuntu/myproject

- app.py
- Only POST. Because I'm using Flask to serve AI model.

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/diagnosis', methods=['POST'])
def diagnosis():
    try:
        [Code omitted...]
    except Exception as e:
        [Code omitted...]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(socket="/run/myproject.sock")
```

- wsgi.py

```
from app import app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

##### Gunicorn

- Gunicorn socket file
  sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/myproject.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket
[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock
[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

- Gunicorn service file
  sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/myproject.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve Flask app
Requires=myproject.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/myproject
Environment="PATH=/home/ubuntu/venv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 5 --timeout 120 --bind unix:/run/myproject.sock wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

##### Nginx

- Nginx conf file
  sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/run/myproject.sock;
        }
}
```

##### Other settings

- Using EC2. Working on default user.(Ubuntu) The website that I followed also worked on ubuntu user.
- Checked EC2 inbound rules: allows http, https, ssh.
- Checked sudo ufw. allows port that I need, allows nginx (80)